# Woocommerce Ajax Validate Checkout Form

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have one step checkout form and need to validate it in realtime without refreshing page, because I have custom payment method that need javascript to trigger the payment process. My problem now is that I could not find any functions or javascript library to validate my form.

What I want is want to get function that return true if the form is valid and return error message when the customer missing or input wrong information.

Please help!!!

Comment: You will find all the necessary material (available hooks and process) in the source code of [`WC_Checkout::process_checkout() method`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#892-947) like building your custom function hooked in `woocommerce_checkout_process` *(or maybe `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`)* action hook(s) …

Comment: how to call function inside that class inside my custom template? @LoicTheAztec

Comment: Where is your related template code?